# SCSS and HAML in Netbeans on remote server?

Tags: php, netbeans

I’m working on a PHP project automatically deployed to a remote server in *NetBeans*. Currently, I’m using regular CSS and HTML which, although I’ve used it for several years, is a bit of a pain when working on bigger applications. Sure I could switch over to *ASP.NET*, but that's not what I’m asking.

Is there a way to compile HAML and SCSS files in NetBeans, then automatically upload them to a server—using the **PHP Application from Remote Server**?

---

It appears to me as though there’s nothing available on the subject, which is why I request this answer and ask this particular question.